# how to use PDF Embed API on my local server with IP address example

Tags: java, pdf, adobe

how to use PDF Embed API on my local server with IP address example

http://172.16.112.83:1100/myfile.pdf

```js
<div id="adobe-dc-view" style="height: 360px; width: 500px;"></div>
<script src="https://documentcloud.adobe.com/view-sdk/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener("adobe_dc_view_sdk.ready", function(){
    var adobeDCView = new AdobeDC.View({clientId: "<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>", divId: "adobe-dc-view"});
    adobeDCView.previewFile({
      content:{ location: 
        { url: "https://documentcloud.adobe.com/view-sdk-demo/PDFs/Bodea%20Brochure.pdf"}},
      metaData:{fileName: "Bodea Brochure.pdf"}
    },
    {
      embedMode: "SIZED_CONTAINER"
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Did you register and get a clientID?

Comment: Yes, I try to get a clientID but is not allowing for an IP address. My application runs on an IP address we don't have the domain as its a local intranet IP address.

Answer (score 3):

Just add "localhost" as domain and create new credential